# How can i respond to the same gsp view from the controller?

Tags: grails, controller

I am pretty new to grails and wondering how to use the respond object to the same view. 
Note: I might not be clear with my question - but please check the below stuffs.

1. I have a one controller called "ProcessController.groovy" which have 2 methods inside them.
2. I have only one gsp called "create.gsp"

   ```
   class PublishedSetController { 
       ...

       def create() {
           Person p = new Person()
           ...

           respond p // Working fine and this forward's to the view "create.gsp"
       }

       def createClone() {
           Person p = new Person()
           p.name = 'joe'
           ...

           // Would like to forward to view "create.gsp"
           respond view: 'create', model: p
       }
   }

   Error:
       Could not resolve view with name 'createClone' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
   ```

I am aware that grails is mostly codeByConvention - but not sure how to fix this issue.
So can anyone please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax for `respond` is:

```
respond p, view: 'create'
```

You can read more about `respond` in the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/respond.html).

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Moore, I was just about to add documentation :)

Comment: No worries, I already had it typed up on my revised answer but you posted before I could finish mine. ;)

Comment: That worked great..I misinterpreted the documentation before - but now it make sense.